# How do I change the Background Color of a Lollipop Toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

How do I change the background color of the Android Lollipop *Toolbar* in Xamarin Studio?

I've tried many different things with no luck, but here's what I've currently got, and it just doesn't work. Pay close attention to the images. For some reason, the bottom of the toolbar is colored (where the dropshadow should be) but not the background of the actual toolbar:

[image]

After adding all the styles and everything, in the Visual Designer, all I see is this (no color background):

[image]

My code:

styles.xml (located directly under resources folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
        ndroid:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="#ffffffff">
    <Toolbar
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.xml (Resources > menu > Main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" android:id="@+id/menu_share" android:title="Share" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Anyone know how I can change the background color of the *Toolbar*?

---

UPDATE:

---

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="#ffffff">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</LinearLayout>
```

color.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
   <!-- Color : Classic colors -->
   <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
   <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
  <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Value : Color -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="ToolbarSample.ToolbarSample">
    <uses-sdk />
    <application android:label="ToolbarSample" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I think `Toolbar` follows `android:colorPrimary` from your application's theme.

Comment: @shkschneider I have no idea where or how to put that. Could you please expand on that?

Comment: In your application's theme https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Comment: @shkschneider I think the code snippet on that page should go into the styles.xml file? I've done that now, and added my own color (#26B0FB), but the toolbar color is still the same.

Comment: Have you linked your theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file? use `android:theme=""` in the `application` tag. All that is basic android theming...

Comment: @shkschneider Yeah but I get this error: C:\Users\Jase\Documents\Projects\ToolbarSample\ToolbarSample\Resources\layout\main.xml(0,0): Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay'). (ToolbarSample)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolbar is like a view, so you can change his backgroundColor like this in `Main.xml`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" />
```

You have to define this color in file `color.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <!-- Color : Classic colors -->
   <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
   <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

If you really want to use `android:colorPrimary`.
You can create your own theme in your file `styles.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
  <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Value : Color -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And use `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` instead.

By the way, to use this theme in all your activities, you have to declare him in your `AndroidManifest.xml` by adding `android:theme` :

```
<application
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Hoping this explanation is clear.

Have a nice day !

Comment: Thank you @LeMimit, but I got error: "C:\Users\Jase\Documents\Projects\ToolbarSample\ToolbarSample\Resources\layout\main.xml(0,0): Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?attr/colorPrimary'). (ToolbarSample)" But I put everything there.

Comment: And if you use the solution with `android:background="@color/black"` where you don't use your theme to define the background color of the Toolbar ?

Comment: If I use that solution it doesn't change the color to black. Nothing changes.

Comment: Really strange I changed it like this, it's working fine with me :(

Comment: Can You repost your files with the changes you've made ?

Comment: You don't have any activity to inflate this layout to test this application on a device or a simulateur ? Cause you have to declare this activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I do. I have a Main activity and I also have Main.xml inside menu folder which has the toolbar items (share button) and I inflate the menu in Main activity. I've been testing it in emulator and on my device for the past 5 hours

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know why it doesn't work. I am not using Xamarin Studio. May be you have to set a specific setting in this IDE.

Comment: no worries :) I appreciate your help. I think I just found something though. I'm gonna try it out and post my results if it works.

Comment: I did. This is really embarrassing to say... But this whole time, the sample that Xamarin provides actually has a blue background color on its toolbar. This whole time I've been staring at it and it didn't even occur to me that they changed its color. Lol. Even though I spent hours looking through that code. Somehow... I managed to replicate it. But no idea how I overlooked that.

Comment: Lol ok ! Nice to speak with you :D